# NodeJs function wait until callback return value

Tags: node.js

I want to print the value of `var a` outside the function call. If I run this program, it prints `undefined`.

```
var http = require('http');

var foo = function(req, res){
    var a = xyz('5',function(aa){
        console.log(aa);
        return aa;
    });
    res.end(a);
    console.log(a);
}

function xyz(arg,callback){
    var aa = 55;
    return callback(aa);
}

http.createServer(foo).listen(8000);
console.log('start server');
```

Comment: What is the link between your title and the question ? Where exactly do you try to print `a` ?

Comment: You should visit here first before asking question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your function async and then await xyz()

```
var http = require('http');

var foo = async function(req, res){
  var a = await xyz('5'); 
  res.end(a);
  console.log(a);
}

function xyz(arg){
  var aa = 55;
  return aa;
}

http.createServer(foo).listen(8000);
console.log('start server');
```

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if your problem solved

Comment: How set response to browser ?